# iOS Frequently getting "exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds"

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I am getting this error message in logs from multiple users on multiple iOS devices. Symbolicating this log in Xcode does not seem to point to a specific line of code as being the issue. Is there a way to debug this to find the problem in the code base? Any help is greatly appreciated! Also, if anyone knows what this error code means the app is doing incorrectly is also appreciated! I haven't seen a clear answer online anywhere.

```
    {"app_name":"Skadaddle SalesPro","app_cohort":"2|date=1579530600000&sf=143441&tid=71eda2fbef0b8af5c5da01ccdc1e7a4c43ef438c33dc8113db57d540554dd22f&ttype=e","app_version":"1.0.3","timestamp":"2020-01-20 10:11:01.23 -0600","slice_uuid":"579bb140-62ed-317f-b5d3-84ef26d8f8ac","adam_id":1475519842,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.xselis.Skadaddle-SalesPro","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)","incident_id":"75CF36B2-AAA5-4C02-B970-BFA45F618B7D","is_beta":true,"name":"Skadaddle SalesPro"}
Incident Identifier: 75CF36B2-AAA5-4C02-B970-BFA45F618B7D
Beta Identifier:     FB74DF1E-E144-4F36-961F-DFB4ECC3A12A
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             Skadaddle SalesPro [7230]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9BB605DD-251F-4328-9D46-DBB03C153819/Skadaddle SalesPro.app/Skadaddle SalesPro
Identifier:          com.xselis.Skadaddle-SalesPro
Version:             1 (1.0.3)
AppStoreTools:       11C29
AppVariant:          1:iPhone8,1:13
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.xselis.Skadaddle-SalesPro [1299]


Date/Time:           2020-01-20 10:11:00.8300 -0600
Launch Time:         2020-01-20 09:19:40.6233 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    7.30.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-update watchdog transgression: application<com.xselis.Skadaddle-SalesPro>:7230 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-update | WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 11.140 (user 11.140, system 0.000), 53% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.146, 1% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a30670 0x197a2d000 + 13936
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978cd890 0x1978cb000 + 10384
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978cded4 0x1978cb000 + 11988
3   FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cdbcde8 0x19cd6e000 + 323048
4   FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cdc2230 0x19cd6e000 + 344624
5   FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cd6f8e8 0x19cd6e000 + 6376
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000019bcd8560 0x19b2ca000 + 10544480
7   FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cdc20d4 0x19cd6e000 + 344276
8   FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cdc1cc4 0x19cd6e000 + 343236
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000019bcd843c 0x19b2ca000 + 10544188
10  UIKitCore                       0x000000019bcd797c 0x19b2ca000 + 10541436
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000019bcd82fc 0x19b2ca000 + 10543868
12  UIKitCore                       0x000000019b30dd38 0x19b2ca000 + 277816
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000019b30dfb8 0x19b2ca000 + 278456
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000019bcd804c 0x19b2ca000 + 10543180
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c1f3c4c 0x19b2ca000 + 15899724
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c1f3ad4 0x19b2ca000 + 15899348
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000019b30d590 0x19b2ca000 + 275856
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000019b30e5b8 0x19b2ca000 + 279992
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000019b881248 0x19b2ca000 + 5993032
20  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cd7b248 0x19cd6e000 + 53832
21  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cd9fd28 0x19cd6e000 + 204072
22  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cd84f04 0x19cd6e000 + 93956
23  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cd9fc5c 0x19cd6e000 + 203868
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978cffd8 0x1978cb000 + 20440
26  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cdc4418 0x19cd6e000 + 353304
27  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cdc40e4 0x19cd6e000 + 352484
28  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019cdc460c 0x19cd6e000 + 353804
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd8a00 0x197b2f000 + 694784
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd8958 0x197b2f000 + 694616
31  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd80f0 0x197b2f000 + 692464
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd323c 0x197b2f000 + 672316
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd2adc 0x197b2f000 + 670428
34  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a1b58328 0x1a1b55000 + 13096
35  UIKitCore                       0x000000019bccdae0 0x19b2ca000 + 10500832
36  Skadaddle SalesPro              0x000000010058ec10 0x100588000 + 27664
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000197a5c360 0x197a5b000 + 4960

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a30634 0x197a2d000 + 13876
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a2faa0 0x197a2d000 + 10912
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd8288 0x197b2f000 + 692872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd33a8 0x197b2f000 + 672680
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd2adc 0x197b2f000 + 670428
5   Foundation                      0x0000000197f127f4 0x197f0b000 + 30708
6   Foundation                      0x0000000197f126d4 0x197f0b000 + 30420
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019bd66204 0x19b2ca000 + 11125252
8   Foundation                      0x00000001980430a4 0x197f0b000 + 1278116
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 2 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a30634 0x197a2d000 + 13876
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a2faa0 0x197a2d000 + 10912
2   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x0000000100697a04 0x100588000 + 1112580
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 3 name:  Realm notification listener
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a539a4 0x197a2d000 + 158116
1   Realm                           0x000000010251b2cc 0x102504000 + 94924
2   Realm                           0x000000010251bdac 0x102504000 + 97708
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.google.firebase.firestore.rpc
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a5414c 0x197a2d000 + 160076
1   grpc                            0x00000001033e1b08 0x1033a8000 + 236296
2   grpc                            0x00000001033e39a4 0x1033a8000 + 244132
3   grpc                            0x00000001033d87f0 0x1033a8000 + 198640
4   grpcpp                          0x0000000103679e1c 0x103670000 + 40476
5   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x000000010071e444 0x100588000 + 1664068
6   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x000000010072e7cc 0x100588000 + 1730508
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d3404 0x1978cb000 + 33796
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d3df8 0x1978cb000 + 36344
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dd314 0x1978cb000 + 74516
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b88 0x19796b000 + 48008
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a51c94 0x197a2d000 + 150676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019796ecf8 0x19796b000 + 15608
2   grpc                            0x000000010343ff20 0x1033a8000 + 622368
3   grpc                            0x00000001033e4b44 0x1033a8000 + 248644
4   grpc                            0x0000000103446df0 0x1033a8000 + 650736
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a51c94 0x197a2d000 + 150676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019796ecf8 0x19796b000 + 15608
2   grpc                            0x000000010343ff20 0x1033a8000 + 622368
3   grpc                            0x00000001033e4b44 0x1033a8000 + 248644
4   grpc                            0x0000000103446df0 0x1033a8000 + 650736
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a51c94 0x197a2d000 + 150676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019796ecf8 0x19796b000 + 15608
2   grpc                            0x000000010343ff10 0x1033a8000 + 622352
3   grpc                            0x0000000103449a6c 0x1033a8000 + 662124
4   grpc                            0x0000000103446df0 0x1033a8000 + 650736
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a30634 0x197a2d000 + 13876
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a2faa0 0x197a2d000 + 10912
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd8288 0x197b2f000 + 692872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd33a8 0x197b2f000 + 672680
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197bd2adc 0x197b2f000 + 670428
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000019ae894e8 0x19ae88000 + 5352
6   Foundation                      0x00000001980430a4 0x197f0b000 + 1278116
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a51c94 0x197a2d000 + 150676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019796ecf8 0x19796b000 + 15608
2   grpc                            0x000000010343ff20 0x1033a8000 + 622368
3   grpc                            0x0000000103449a6c 0x1033a8000 + 662124
4   grpc                            0x0000000103446df0 0x1033a8000 + 650736
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197975d8c 0x19796b000 + 44428
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019797976c 0x19796b000 + 59244

Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 11 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 13 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 14 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 15 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 16 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 17 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 18 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 19 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 20 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 21 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 22 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 23 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232

Thread 24 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197a52240 0x197a2d000 + 152128
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be660 0x19784e000 + 460384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001978be460 0x19784e000 + 459872
3   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005bbdbc 0x100588000 + 212412
4   Skadaddle SalesPro              0x00000001005c6ae0 0x100588000 + 256736
5   Async                           0x00000001015ba88c 0x1015b4000 + 26764
6   Async                           0x00000001015ba948 0x1015b4000 + 26952
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978d97dc 0x1978cb000 + 59356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197927184 0x1978cb000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc0d8 0x1978cb000 + 69848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001978dc770 0x1978cb000 + 71536
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197976b48 0x19796b000 + 47944
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197979760 0x19796b000 + 59232
```

Comment: It seems to indicate that your app hung, while consuming CPU for over 10 seconds so it was killed by the watchdog. (8badf00d exception code) during startup. You need to examine your code and determine if it is possible for it to enter an infinite loop on startup.

Answer (score 14):

`EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)` indicates the operating system terminated the process.

OS has `watchdog` to ensure application not drag down the system responsiveness.

- Slow performance will cause OS to abort your app. `20 sec`

  - Maintain system responsiveness
  - Beware the system “watchdog”
- Launch and resume are particularly important `10 sec`
- Smooth scrolling, `6 sec`

The following table comes  from  [session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/312/),

[image]

Then you can look at the exception reason field. In your case, the exception reason `0x8badf00d`(pronounced “ate bad food”).

> Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-update watchdog transgression: application<com.xselis.Skadaddle-SalesPro>:7230 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-update | WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 11.140 (user 11.140, system 0.000), 53% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.146, 1% CPU" | )

According to this, it looks like your App did resume from background within 10 seconds

You can also check [Understanding the Exception Types in a Crash Report](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/understanding_the_exception_types_in_a_crash_report#3582412)
 and [Aware Watchdog Termination](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_watchdog_terminations)

For example, the following crash comes from block main-thread for about 20 seconds

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-create watchdog transgression: application<com.wangya.test2>:21021 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.99 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 4.720 (user 4.720, system 0.000), 4% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.031, 0% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

> Noted that if your process is detached by debugger in Xcode, the system watch dog is disabled. You won't trigger this kind of crash.  But you can disable debugger in Xcode by unchecking `edit scheme -> run -> info -> debug executable`
> [image]

https://suelan.github.io/2021/03/05/20210305-crash-ate-bad-food/

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly likely that your app is doing a network call on the main thread and is spending more time on network connection, thus updating UIs based on the network resources is delayed. The system's watchdog killed the app due to unresponsiveness. You can find the hints in @RY_Zheng answer as well.

To solve this find places where network calls could interfere main thread, try moving them to a background thread. Always keep the UI as responsive as possible.